# Docker container does not run on a EC2 instance part of EC2 Cluster

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, containers

I am trying to automate the deployment process of my project. The environment looks like:

- we use GitLab to store our code
- we execute a CD/CI pipeline within GitLab to build a Docker image and to store it in Amazon repository
- once the build stage is completed, Docker have to run in deployment stage the latest image on the first of two instances and after successful execution to scale the containers on the second instance.

This is how the .gutlab-ci.yml file looks like:

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:dind
stages:
  - build
  - deploy
variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

testBuild:
 stage: build
 script:
   - docker login -u AWS -p <password> <link to Amazons' repo>
   - docker build -t <repo/image:latest> app/
   - docker push <repo/image:latest>

testDeploy:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "us-east-2"
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "access key"
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "ssecretAK"
    AWS_CLUSTER: "testCluster"
    AWS_SIZE: "2"

  before_script:
    - apk add --update curl
    - curl -o /usr/local/bin/ecs-cli https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazon-ecs-cli/ecs-cli-linux-amd64-latest
    - chmod +x /usr/local/bin/ecs-cli

  script:
    - docker login -u AWS -p <password> <repo_link>
    - docker run --rm --name <name-ofcontainer> -p 80:8000 -i <repo/image:latest>
    - ecs-cli configure --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --access-key $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID --secret-key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY --cluster $AWS_CLUSTER
    - ecs-cli scale --capability-iam --size $AWS_SIZE

  only:
    - development
```

Now when the script is successfully executed I SSH the instances and and enter `docker ps -a` it does not list a running container also it does not find the image with `docker image`.

If I enter manually the commands on one of the instances the website is available.

My questions is how to make the container available?

**EDIT 1:**

We use shared runner, if this is what you asks. The reason we use docker:dind is because when we do not use it the following error occurs and we cannot go further:

```
Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?). Using system default: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Comment: What gitlab executor are you using? Because you run docker image and then run a `docker:dind` service. You create a image inside this and run it, when your CI ends the containers end and so do the containers you ran inside. You need to run shell executor in your case on the host machine

Comment: @TarunLalwani check EDIT 1 please

Comment: You problem is the executor. Please read the various executors https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/. From what you are asking you probably need a Shell executor on main machine or you want to share the docker socket from main machine. See this article also https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html